# Is it java error?

Tags: java

When I try to execute a Java application, I get an error .

```
'Could not find _JNI_GetEntryPoints@0 in dynamic library xx.dll
```

I want to know if it is a generic JAVA related error (such as some problem with java installation on my windows computer?) or it is specific error related to the application only. If it is installation error, what kind of files/libraries i should install? Thanks.

Comment: "Java" is not an acronym and should not be written in all caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would normally mean that you are using wrong version of xx.dll.

Comment: Or that xx.dll is not properly registered...I think =)

Comment: @jadarnel27, could you say how can i register? or see if it is registered? im using windows.

Comment: @Suraj Chandran, did you mean, version incompatible with JDK? Is there anyway to check the version?

Comment: i mean version incompatible with whichever code needs it, mostly it wont be jdk, what is the name of the dll?

Comment: You can go in a command prompt window (with admin rights), browse to the folder where the xx.dll is, then type `regsrvr32 xx.dll`